# VBA ADODB Connection -SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, vba, connection, adodb

I am Running in VBA But same is not working. Getting error no Value Given for one or more Required Parameter.

My Query :

esql = "Select MAPPING_MONTH.DT,SUM(MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO.COUNT) as GA_COUNT From MAPPING_MONTH A LEFT OUTER JOIN MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO B on A.DT=B.DATE where ((MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO.CIRCLE)= " & """" & FName & "GROUP BY MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO.CIRCLE"")"

RS.Open (esql), CN, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Comment: I notice that you are aliasing the tables A and B but only using the alias in the join condition, not in the select, where or group by clauses. This may be causing the problem.

Comment: The error is probably caused by the line: `"""" & FName & "GROUP BY MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO.CIRCLE"")"`... you need a space between `FName` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

While there is some code missing which could be helpful in debugging the code here are some improvements which (potentially) already resolve your problem. If that's not the case then you might want to consider updating your post and include more of your code (where you declare `RS` and `CN` and setup the `ADODB.Connection`).

Having said that here are the suggested changes:

```
esql = "      select  MAPPING_MONTH.DT, "
esql = esql & "        sum(MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO.COUNT) as GA_COUNT "
esql = esql & "from    MAPPING_MONTH A "
esql = esql & "left outer join MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO B "
esql = esql & "on      A.DT = B.DATE "
esql = esql & "where   MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO.CIRCLE = N'" & FName & "' " 
sql = esql & "group by MAIL_ACTIVE_Base_Tracker_GA_AM_AO.CIRCLE "

RS.Open esql, CN, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Changes:

1. Remove the brackets around `esql` in the `RS.Open` line.
2. Remove the brackets inside the constructed T-SQL statement
3. Exchange the `"` inside your T-SQL for `'` to include the file name as text.